# Call Delphi code in iOS from TWebBrowser

Tags: android, ios, delphi, delphi-xe5

Is there a sample code or existing procedure to call Delphi code from `TWebBrowser` in iOS and/or Android app ?

I'm using a `TWebBrowser` for a form process and will like to know when the user is done with the process in `TWebBrowser` interfacing with a webserver.

```
twebbrowser.url := 'http://www.loginform.php';
```

How can I detect that user has completed form and is ready for the next stage ?

Comment: Could you check, does TWebBrowser for iOS has event OnDocumentComplete ?

Comment: I suppose you are using Delphi XE5, right?

Comment: @Zam, there's currently no other Delphi version which supports Android, so yes, it is Delphi XE5.